# R Shiny print HTML text in renderplot

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny is it possible to have in the Server part of the App in the renderPlot function something like this:

```
output$plotting <- renderPlot({
    if (value == 1 ) {
        grid.arrange(plot1, plot2,nrow=1, ncol=2)
    } else {
    # Print a generic message with an h1() or p() function.
    }
})
```

I'm able to render the plot, yet not able to print a generic message. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`renderPlot` expects an expression that generates a plot. Accordingly you can't pass html tags to it.

However, you can use `conditionalPanel` to display UI elements based on a condition:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("toggle", "toggle"),
  conditionalPanel("input.toggle == true", plotOutput("myPlot")),
  conditionalPanel("input.toggle == false", p("Generic message"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({plot(1:10)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

An alternative approach can be realized by using [a hidden tabsetPanel](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-visibility) or  `renderUI`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("toggle", "toggle"),
  uiOutput("myUIOutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({plot(1:10)})
  
  output$myUIOutput <- renderUI({
    if(input$toggle == TRUE){
      plotOutput("myPlot")
    } else {
      p("Generic message")
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```